# Protected sheet prevent certain Google script functions to run properly

Tags: google-apps-script, protected

I have a sheet that's protected in some area like `V1:V12`. It however prevent certain script functions to run in a completely different range like `.getLastRow()`, `getRange("K5:K100").clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true})`,`sheet.deleteRows(15,15)`. Also *getting value in protected range* `getRange("V3").getValue` also cannot run. They all give error that you need permission to edit range. I ended up removes all protections and the script run normally.

Just to be clear, I create protection from the owner's account. The certain script functions cannot run for editors account after ranges in sheet protected. There are many other script functions still run correctly. The script run correctly for the owner account (of course). I removed protection by using the owner account, after that, the script run fine for editors.

I really need the sheet to be protected (so the user will not mess up the functionality), is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In short, not really, you can add permissions for specific editors in the protected ranges, but if the protections are set up, the scripts risk not running. If the script doesn't affect the range then it should run, but otherwise, as you've seen, you won't be able to even get the value. A potential workaround would be to have the script remove the protection, do its thing and then add them again, but this is risky if multiple people are working on the sheet simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is probably a bug that need to be reported. It seems like not many people come across this which is rather strange to me.

Comment: It's actually intended behavior, the idea of having protected ranges is that people can't access/change the information. Think for example, if you hid the rows with protected ranges because that data is confidential, users w/o permissions wouldn't be able to unhide them to see or retrieve the data in any particular way (including scripts).

Comment: I agree with you on the `getValue()` function. But the others, I don't. Deleting content in `K15:K100` do not affect `V1:V12` in anyway. Neither does `getLastRow()` and others. If Google thinks they do because protected ranges are dependencies of other ranges, they make mistake. The protection should mean to protect the formula, not the result of formulas.

Comment: Do you mean that in your `V1:V12` you have the formulas or the result? Because They'd protect against changing the results if the results are in the protected range, they don't allow any changes into the protected range; that would include the changes from a formula

Comment: I just ran a small test, I had a cell `a` with a formula that added 10 to a value from cell `b` (unprotected). A separate user was able to change `b` and the formula in `a` would work, I tried changing with a script, using an `onOpen` and it worked too, the second user was only unable to directly alter cell `a`. I would suggest you look into your protected ranges (**data -> protected sheets and ranges**) to make sure that your ranges are not covering more than you think

Comment: My script were mostly run on `onEdit`. Also, I tried so many times. Near the end, only range `V1:V2` were protected and the script function still have problems. I made sure that `V1:V2` was not a dependencies nor precedent of any script-manipulated ranges.
I also think that protecting the result in script-changes but allow it in manual edit doesn't make sense. The information should be protected, if it's formula then protect the formula, if it's value then protect the value.

Comment: So is what you want to avoid having the values updated from the `onEdit` if they are protected?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. My problem is script failed to run when the sheet have certain range protected.

Comment: The script should not fail if it's not affecting a protected range, you could test in a new sheet, perhaps there was a protected range you did not know about

Comment: It recently does not fail anymore. Must be something changed from Google's end. Since Sheet list protected ranges in it side bar, there is no way I missed anything.

Comment: Glad it's working now!